# Create Directory with ls and Create-Item

Tags: powershell

I wanted to create in another directory the same folders of another directory (which contains about 234 folders).

My ideas was

```
Ls -Name | New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path D:\Test\
```

I get then multiple times the error that the `D:\Test` path already exsits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work, as the directory creation part `New-Item -ItemType` never uses the value from pipeline.

What's more, you don't filter the output from `ls`, so any non-directory files are processed too.

```
# Get a list of folders only
gci | ? { $_.psIsContainer } | % { 
  # create a dir. Uses join-path and $_.name to combine new root dir with directory's name
  new-item -itemtype directory -path $(join-path "d:\myroot" $_.name)
}
```